# Form1 cannot be closed before Form2 Closed in windows application C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, Form1 and Form2, after opening Form1 I have to open Form2, if I click on Form1 close dialog that should not be closed before closing the Form2.

Comment: make Form2 modal, use ShowDialog for second form.

Comment: Show the code you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Form.ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) method instead of Show() when you display the child form.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply open `Form2` using `Form2.ShowDialog()`: it this is called from `Form1` code then `Form2` is *modal* with respect to Form1 (that is you can interact no more with Form1 until you close `Form2`) and so the user is forced to close `Form2` before being able to close `Form1`.

Please mark this answer as accepted if it responds your question.

Answer (score 0):

Code below. Maybe this is what you need.

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need interact with both windows?
If only Form2 gets the attention, you can solve it with the mentioned ShowDialog ().
Otherwise you can check with OnClosing if Form2 still open and refuse it.
Here you have a nice code snip to disable the close button:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/32148556-2640-4d79-a7b6-f13f9ce3420a/how-to-enabledisable-the-close-buttonx-in-window-form-?forum=winforms